# how to connect a set of isolated vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

given a set of  vertices in a plane, selecting a point as entrance, a point near the entrance as exit, how should I connect them that the edge of any two successive points do not larger than certain max value?
such as below , * stand for vertices, given a point as In, than exit from a point near the entrance , is there any algorithm to do this???? help?

```
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  <------ in 
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  * <------- out
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
*   *   *  *   *  *   *   *
* *  *   *   *   *  *   * *
```

Comment: Have you tried brute-force? Also, your problem statement is not clear. Are the points on a regular grid or randomly distributed? Do you want to connect all points? Are edges allowed to cross? Are entrance and/or exit given or should the algorithm select them? And, finally, is this question really a programming question?

Comment: @kazemakase, sorry for my misleading, yes ,  the points are on a regular grid , and I must connect all the points. edges are allowed to cross. the entrance point is manually selected and the exit point should be selected near the entrance by algorithm. Actually, I am an IC physical design engineer, I have a lot of cells in the layout, I want to connect them by metal layers. certainlly this is a programming issue

Answer (score 2):

If the points are placed on a regular grid, and no points are missing the solution is relatively simple (A, B, C). An issue could arise in case the grid has both, an odd number of rows and an odd number of columns, and if the diagonal distance between points is larger than your maximum allowed distance (D).

[image]

You may also want to check out the [Moore curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_curve) or [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) in general if you are interested in theoretical properties of possible solutions.

I think the problems becomes rather complex if the points are not evenly spaced, or not all positions on the grid are occupied.

Comment: Wow, thank you @kazemakase,  "I think the problems becomes rather complex if the points are not evenly spaced, or not all positions on the grid are occupied."  Well, that is the case, some position may open, thank you for your info , I will have a try,

Comment: @MingguoPeng You could simply pretend the positions are not open, but that might violate your maximum distance constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search):

```
  # Input: G (set of vertices), v (entry vertex)
  procedure BFS(G,v) is
      let Q be a queue
      Q.enqueue(v)
      label v as discovered
      while Q is not empty
         v ← Q.dequeue()
         process(v)
         for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
             if w is not labeled as discovered
                Q.enqueue(w)
                label w as discovered
```

`G.adjacentEdges(v)` would search for vertices that are close enough, but have not yet been discovered. `process(v)` would test whether `v` is the exit vertex. Each vertex would also have to remember how it was reached from the entry vertex.

Comment: thank you for your advice, but all the vertices are isolated, they have no connection, and I want to  connect them sequentially to generate a line, from in to out. do you have any suggestion? @Oswald

Comment: They might not have a connection, but they have a distance (as implied by your statement that *the edge of any two successive points do not larger than certain max value*). For the purpose of breadth-first-search, this can be interpreted as *having a connection*.

Comment: Anyway, since you clarified that you need to connect **all** vertices, you should go with the solution of kazemakase.